# PIG: ERROR 1200: <line 15, column 66> mismatched input '==' expecting RIGHT

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have an error when execute the test statement

```
F = foreach D generate flatten(group),SUM(r1.description == 'COLLECTION' ? r1.scoring : null),SUM(r1.lookup_descrition== 'Probability' ? r1.scoring: null);
```

The error message

```
2017-01-13 09:12:42,368 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 15, column 66>  mismatched input '==' expecting RIGHT_PAREN
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a space `r1.lookup_descrition==`

```
F = foreach D generate flatten(group),
          SUM(r1.description == 'COLLECTION' ? r1.scoring : null),
          SUM(r1.lookup_descrition == 'Probability' ? r1.scoring : null);
```

Comment: Still got the same error even if I can simplify statement:

Comment: f = foreach d generate flatten(group),SUM(r1.description  ==  'COLLECTION' ? r1.scoring : null);

Comment: I have the spaces before and after ==

Comment: 2017-01-13 22:16:04,166 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 14, column 64>  mismatched input '==' expecting RIGHT_PAREN